# Replace coalesce with case

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

How can I refactor this query so there is no COALESCE or ISNULL? Can I change it so it uses CASE? Is there any other way to refactor it?

```
SELECT * FROM MockDb WHERE 
COALESCE(Column1,0) = @value1 AND 
COALESCE(Column2,0) = @value2 AND 
COALESCE(Column3,0) = @value3 AND 
COALESCE(Column4,0) = @value4 AND 
COALESCE(Column5,0) = @value5
```

Comment: `... where (@value1 is null or Column1 = @value1) AND ... `

Comment: Why you need this replacement?

Comment: What logic are you trying to implement?  This is unusual logic, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like strange logic -- treat `NULL` values in the columns as if they were "0".

You can write:

```
where (column1 = @value1 or @value1 = 0 and column1 is null) and
      (column2 = @value2 or @value2 = 0 and column2 is null) and
      . . .
```

Normally, the concern is to allow `NULL` values for the parameters.  I would expect to see logic such as:

```
where (column1 = @value1 or @value1 is null) and
      (column2 = @value2 or @value2 is null) and
      . . .
```

This version treats `NULL` values in the parameter as "ignore this column for filtering purposes".  Your version deals with `NULL` values in the column itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace

```
coalesce(column1, 0)
```

with

```
case when column1 is null then 0 else column1 end
```

However, you could make another condition:

```
(column1=@value1) OR (column1 is null AND @value1=0)
```